# Why is there a visible shadow gap between hair particles and my mesh? can this gap be removed?

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

There's like a tiny pocket of air between the mesh and hair, can this be fixed?

[image]

Comment: I do not see you having added a particle system on the right the particle system field is empty, I do see you added a Bezier curve, your hair follicles do not look like the ones used in the hair system. how did you add the hair? I am pretty sure you created meshes and put them on top with a modifier that is not adding the meshes straight on top of the plane but has a slight distance set from it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @BrechtCorbeel Sorry I changed the screenshot to a better one, I am using a hair particle system, not curves

Comment: Could it be the jitter and random order doing it? I am 100% certain some of your hair particles are floating above the plane. You likely have something set the wrong way which is making the bottom of the strand bend and curve above the plane.

Answer (score -1):

From the image I can tell you tried creating hair with modifiers and a meshed bezier curve.

You need to create a particle system for hair on your plane, likely need to select the vertexes you would like to add it to and then use the grooming system to modify the hair.

Update:
You could add a slightly expanded mesh with no hair to mitigate this.

Comment: I replaced the screenshot with a clearer one, I am using hair particle systems, not curves

Comment: @ you could add a slightly enlarged mesh to mitigate this. without any hair particles on it